# Multi-Dimensional Array from two Arrays where unique values match

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create my first API using Node.js (also a first). I have two arrays, "rooms" and "room_availability" I would like to add all "room_availability" to "rooms" where the room code matches. If there I didn't provide enough code below to help, please let me know, but I think this should do it.

rooms Array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 61,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Standard View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "ZA",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Resort Grounds or Parking Area",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-standard.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-standard-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "SZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 63,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Garden/Pool View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "AZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "View of Pool, Water or Garden Areas",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-gardenpool.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-gardenpool-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 64,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "1-Bedroom Villa",
    "view": "Standard View",
    "roomcat": "onebed",
    "roomcode": "ZB",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "712",
    "description": "Views of Resort Grounds or Parking Area",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa - NO ADDITIONAL BEDDING",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-1br.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-1br-standard.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-1br-standard-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 65,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "1-Bedroom Villa",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "onebed",
    "roomcode": "OZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "712",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa - NO ADDITIONAL BEDDING",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-1br.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-1br-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-1br-boardwalk-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 66,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "1-Bedroom Villa",
    "view": "Garden/Pool View",
    "roomcat": "onebed",
    "roomcode": "BZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "712",
    "description": "View of Pool, Water or Garden Areas",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa - NO ADDITIONAL BEDDING",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-1br.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-1br-gardenpool.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-1br-gardenpool-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 67,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa",
    "view": "Standard View",
    "roomcat": "twobed",
    "roomcode": "ZL",
    "sleeps": 9,
    "sqfoot": "1,072",
    "description": "Views of Resort Grounds or Parking Area",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-2br-lo.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-standard.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-standard-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 68,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "twobed",
    "roomcode": "TZ",
    "sleeps": 9,
    "sqfoot": "1,072",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-2br-lo.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-boardwalk-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 69,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "2-Bedroom Lock-Off Villa",
    "view": "Garden/Pool View",
    "roomcat": "twobed",
    "roomcode": "LZ",
    "sleeps": 9,
    "sqfoot": "1,072",
    "description": "View of Pool, Water or Garden Areas",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-2br-lo.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-gardenpool.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-2br-lo-gardenpool-thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 70,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "3-Bedroom Grand Villa",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "threebed",
    "roomcode": "DZ",
    "sleeps": 12,
    "sqfoot": "2,142",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 king-size bed, 4 queen-size beds, 1 queen-size sleeper sofa",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-3br.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-3br-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-3br-boardwalk-thumb.jpg"
  }
]
```

room_availability Array:

```
[
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "AZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "AZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "AZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "AZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 16
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "BZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "BZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 1,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "BZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "BZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 29
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "DZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 1,
    "points": 76
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "DZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 76
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "DZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 1,
    "points": 76
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "DZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 1,
    "points": 88
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "LZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "LZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "LZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "LZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 40
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "OZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "OZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "OZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "OZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 29
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "SZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "SZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "SZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 14
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "SZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 16
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "TZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "TZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "TZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "TZ",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 40
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZA",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZA",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZA",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZA",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 13
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZB",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 19
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZB",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 19
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZB",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 19
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZB",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 27
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZL",
    "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 29
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZL",
    "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 29
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZL",
    "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 29
  },
  {
    "resort": "BWALK",
    "room": "ZL",
    "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "available": 0,
    "points": 35
  }
]
```

My Javascript (what I have tried):

```
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.get("/resort-info/rooms", async (req, res) => {
    const rooms = await getRooms()
    res.send(rooms);
})

app.get("/resort-info/room/:roomcode", async (req, res) => {
    const roomcode = req.params.roomcode
    const room = await getRoom(roomcode)
    res.send(room);
})

app.get("/resort-info/resort/:resort", async (req, res) => {
    const resort = req.params.resort
    const resort_rooms = await getRoomsByResort(resort)
    res.send(resort_rooms);
})

app.get("/resort-info/room-availability/start/:start/end/:end", async (req, res) => {
    const rooms = await getRooms()
    const start = req.params.start
    const end = req.params.end
    const room_availability = await getRoomAvailability(start, end)
    
    let combined = rooms.map(item => ({ ...item,
      dates: room_availability.filter(f => f.roomcode == item.roomcode)
    }));
    
    
    //res.send(room_availability);
    //res.send(rooms);
    res.send(combined);
})
```

Current results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 61,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Standard View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "ZA",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Resort Grounds or Parking Area",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-standard.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-standard-thumb.jpg",
    "dates": []
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "SZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk-thumb.jpg",
    "dates": []
  }
]
```

Desired results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 61,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Standard View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "ZA",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Resort Grounds or Parking Area",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-standard.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-standard-thumb.jpg",
    "dates": [
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "ZA",
        "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 9
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "ZA",
        "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 9
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "ZA",
        "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 9
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "ZA",
        "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 13
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "resort": "Boardwalk Villas",
    "room": "Deluxe Studio",
    "view": "Boardwalk View",
    "roomcat": "studio",
    "roomcode": "SZ",
    "sleeps": 5,
    "sqfoot": "359",
    "description": "Views of Boardwalk",
    "bedding": "1 queen-size bed, 1 full-size sleeper sofa, 1 single pull-down bed",
    "resort_link": "../boardwalk",
    "layout_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_layout/bwv/bwv-studio.jpg",
    "room_img": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_image/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk.jpg",
    "roomimg_thumb": "../images/checkavail-imgs/room_thumb/bwv/bwv-studio-boardwalk-thumb.jpg",
    "dates": [
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "SZ",
        "staydate": "2023-09-05T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 14
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "SZ",
        "staydate": "2023-09-06T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 14
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "SZ",
        "staydate": "2023-09-07T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 14
      },
      {
        "resort": "BWALK",
        "room": "SZ",
        "staydate": "2023-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
        "available": 0,
        "points": 16
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the property from `room_availability` object. Are you trying to compare the `f.roomcode` that doesn't exist in the object with the `item.roomcode`. Replace to `f.room` and the code will work

```
let combined = rooms.map(item => ({ ...item,
  dates: room_availability.filter(f => f.room == item.roomcode)
}));
```

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. I can't believe I overlooked that. I appreciate the help.